# SQL Server - add DATE part of DATETIME to TIME part of DATETIME

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

In SQL Server 2005 I am interrogating some old legacy data and I need to combine the date component of a datetime column with the time component from another column. Here's an example:

```
DateColumn: 2016-05-09 00:00:00.000
TimeColumn: 1899-12-30 12:26:00.000
```

I need the end result converted to the following DateTime:

```
ResultDateTime: 2016-05-09 12:26:00.000
```

I tried using:

```
CAST(DateColumn AS DATETIME) + CAST(TimeColumn AS TIME) AS ResultDateTime
```

But SQL Server 2005 doesn't recognize the type TIME.

Can someone please show me a way of doing that?

Many thanks!

Comment: `dateadd(ss, datediff(ss,'18991230'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use `DATEADD` and `DATEDIFF`, assuming that the time column's date portion is always 30/12/1899:

```
declare @t table (DateColumn datetime,TimeColumn datetime)
insert into @t(DateColumn,TimeColumn) values
('2016-05-09T00:00:00.000','1899-12-30T12:26:00.000')

select DATEADD(millisecond,DATEDIFF(millisecond,'18991230',TimeColumn),DateColumn)
from @t
```

Result:

```
-----------------------
2016-05-09 12:26:00.000
```

Answer (score 3):

convert the time column to string HH:MM:SS and add to the date column

```
ResultDatetIme = DateColumn + convert(varchar(10), TimeColumn, 108)
```

Answer (score 1):

As you can see following data type supported in SQL 2005: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819(v=sql.90).aspx

Use datetime and smalldatetime, The smalldatetime data type stores dates and times of day with less precision than datetime. The Database Engine stores smalldatetime values as two 2-byte integers. The first 2 bytes store the number of days after January 1, 1900. The other 2 bytes store the number of minutes since midnight.
datetime values are rounded to increments of .000, .003, or .007 seconds, as shown in the following table.

```
SELECT CAST('2016-05-09 00:00:00.000' AS DATETIME) + CAST('1900-01-01 12:26:00.000' AS smalldatetime) AS ResultDateTime
Result: 2016-05-09 12:26:00.000
```

So you can use datetime and smalldatetime, hope fully that will work for you.
Let me know if any issue. love to resolve :)

Comment: I tried this and it returned: The conversion from datetime data type to smalldatetime data type resulted in a smalldatetime overflow error.

Comment: This will work because year 1900 below is the reason of error
SELECT CAST('2016-05-09 00:00:00.000' AS DATETIME) + CAST('1900-01-01 12:26:00.000' AS smalldatetime) AS ResultDateTime

Comment: this ia working:
SELECT CAST('2016-05-09 00:00:00.000' AS DATETIME) + CAST('1900-01-01 12:26:00.000' AS smalldatetime) AS ResultDateTime